# Difference of work

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, verbs

actually I have a confusion of saying work in, work at and work for.

Now I am working at Vodafone is it right?

is it right to say I am working as a technical support at Vodafone or for Vodafone and what is the difference between work for and work at, besides can I say in this field or on this field? I think also I could say in a technical department. hopefully, you can clarify my confusion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Working for a company is correct. Working at the company location is correct. Working with the company's employees is correct. The short way to put it if someone asks is "I'm working for/at/with Vodafone." Leaving out the details while varying the preposition is not unusual. If your division is a subset of the corporation then you are working under Vodafone. The context is usually helped by the proposition.

If you see strange or odd prepositions you can try and interpret the meaning for fun. What if you work along side of Vodafone, then you are selling hot dogs in the parking lot.

Comment: *sue. Should it be see? (Welcome to ELU, you should be able to edit your answer).